# Find a range of an object in google apps script

Tags: object, google-apps-script, range

I am a newbie with coding and am trying to get the minimum value of a column (of a temporary sheet) and then copy that value and some data from the corresponding row to another sheet. For some reason it seems to work only once during the loop, is it because I'm trying to define a range based on an object?

```
    function create_filter(){
    const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("APperCountry");
    const sheet2 =ss.getSheetByName("Tender");
    
    var lanelist = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow(), 8).getValues();
    var country = ('B:B');
    var origin = ('E:E');
  
    

for(var i=2; i<=lanelist.length;i++){
  
  Logger.log("Filter has been added.");
  country = ('B'+i);
  Logger.log(country);
  var origin = ('E'+i)
  var calc = ('M'+i);
  var apname = ('N'+i);
  const ori = sheet2.getRange(origin);

  if(ori.isBlank()){
  continue;
  }  

  const  range = sheet1.getRange("A:D");
  const  filter = range.createFilter();
  var Ctry = sheet2.getRange(country).getValue();
  const  Filter_Criteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(Ctry);
  const coll1 = 1;
  const  add_filter1 =  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1,Filter_Criteria1);
  const  new_sheet = ss.insertSheet();
  new_sheet.setName("AirportDistanceCalc");
  var tempsheet = ss.getSheetByName('AirportDistanceCalc');

  range.copyTo(new_sheet.getRange(1,1));

var aplist = new_sheet.getRange(2, 1, new_sheet.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValues();

new_sheet.getRange(1,5,1,1).setValue("Origin")
new_sheet.getRange(1,6,1,1).setValue("DistanceKM")

for(var j=0; j<aplist.length;j++){
  
  Logger.log(origin);

  ori.copyTo(new_sheet.getRange(j+2,5));

  mainFun()
  }
  let comparisonRange = tempsheet.getRange("F2:F");
  let comparisonRangeValues = comparisonRange.getValues().filter(String);
  let minimum = comparisonRangeValues[0][0];

  comparisonRangeValues.forEach((rowItem, rowIndex) => {
    comparisonRangeValues[rowIndex].forEach((columnItem) => {
      minimum = Math.min(minimum, columnItem);

    });
  });

  console.log(minimum);
  sheet2.getRange(calc).setValue(minimum);
  tempsheet.getRange(minimum, 2).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(apname));

  if (tempsheet) {
    ss.deleteSheet(tempsheet);
  }
  filter.remove();
}  
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with `if (ori.isBlank())`, if you comment the if you will find other errors, but seems like because of it, the script does not run further. Can you share a copy with dummy data of the sheet and what is the intention of the script?

Comment: I'm unable to upload a file here. Here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cx1tAYpkZzcN3I0Dm1yavdUch6hXYTjHD7NwuFlYLgQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share it publicly accessible? It is access restricted now

Comment: My bad. Please check with this link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18-IGJVWOuOhALHhREGrDDSqMSQpQU_hVPihPCfzPjHI/edit?usp=sharing

The intention of the script is to compare a list addresses vs a list of possible airports per country and return the closest one for each line (the distance to the airport and the airport name).

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also, on the sheet shared there is only one sheet `Sheet1` and the code requires two sheets `APperCountry` and `Tender`. Can you confirm if `Sheet1` is the equivalent of one of the two sheets required and what is the content of the other sheet?

Comment: Sorry, I had to make a copy and forgot the other tab. Just updated the file and tab names (and gave editor rights).

I don't get any errors, that's the thing, but only the first cell from the "Airport" column is populated.

Comment: It seems that the issue is that the code can't get properly the France airport.

I have tried it with Canada and it did work `No; Canada; Vancouver; V5S; Vancouver V5S, Canada; France; Bondy; 93160; 93140 Bondy, France; NO MATCH; NO MATCH; NO; 12.564; Halifax / Stanfield International Airport`

For what I could find also, seems like the distances are not correct. On Melbourne, the airport should be the Melbourne one and not Sidney. I am trying to find out more on this but I thought this information could also help you.

Answer (score 0):

#### The minimum of a column

```
function mincolumn(col=1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const min = sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(e => !isNaN(e)).sort((a,b) => a - b)[0];
  Logger.log(min);
}
```